# How to disable tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `tbody` inside which there are `href`/`input` `type` `text`/ etc

I have a code to get all elements of `tbody` but how to disable it.

My tbody

```
<tbody id="FamilyHistory_3">
<tr>
  <td class="tablecell">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a id="FamilyHistory_3" name="316098" value="316098" onclick="javascript:save('FamilyHistory_3','test');" href="#">
      <img style="border-style: none" src="../images/v10/arrow_doc.png">
    </a>&nbsp;test
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="tablecell">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="10627_316098">Yes 
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="No" name="10627_316098">No&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="2px"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is my code to get the content of `tbody`

```
function save(inputID,category){

var content= document.querySelectorAll('#tbodyID');

  for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++){
    // how to disable all the elements inside it
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `document.getElementById('tbodyID')`? and what do you mean by `disable`?

Comment: @BeatAlex I want make every thing read only like checkbox/radio button disable, input text readonly.

Comment: Got ya, check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to loop, jquery can deal with groups of elements just using selectors.

Use the Jquery selectors and the [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to add `disabled="disabled"` to each one.

You can also select multiple items using a [comma separated list](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#tbodyID input, #tbodyID select, ....').prop('disabled', true);
```

disabling an `a` tag will not prevent it from being clicked though. May be better to `hide()` these.

```
$('#tbodyID a').hide();
```

Comment: input tag are getting disabled but anchor tag is not getting disabled.What is the value for drop down like a for anchor, input for input.

Comment: which is why I said *disabling an a tag will not prevent it from being clicked though*. a tags don't support disabled.

Comment: Added some more info on this.

Answer (score 4):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NbBB/)

```
document.querySelector('#tbodyID input').disabled = true;
```

You don't need jQuery for this.

For more than one:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXyd2/)

```
var l = document.querySelectorAll('#tbodyID input');

for (i = 0;i<l.length;i++)
{
    l[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Good no jquery alternative

Comment: Bear in mind you may have problems if you're supporting old version of IE http://caniuse.com/queryselector. Stupid IE....

Comment: Even so, jQuery 2.0 stops supporting IE8 and below ;) @Liam

Comment: I wish I had that option :( still widely used in some countries.

Comment: You'll never get 100% of the internet happy with something. Just pure JS I feel is always better than jQuery where possible. @Liam

Comment: Agree, it was 100% more of a bear in mind. Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to specify the types of all elements you want to disable. If you have jQuery, you can do that with something like this:

```
$('#tbodyID').find('a, input').prop('disabled', true);
```

**Explanation**

- `$('#tbodyID')` : Select the element with id `tbodyID`
- `find('a, input')` : Find all the `a` and `input` elements inside it
- `prop('disabled', true)` : Set the `disabled` property of each element returned by the previous command

Comment: @Liam It removes the need to mention `#tbodyID` multiple times

Comment: @Liam `$('#tbodyID').find('a, input')` is actually faster than `$('#tbodyID a, #tbodyID input')`.

Comment: Disable an anchor doesn't give expected result

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer finally I accomplished my task using below code. I know you people have already answer but then also I am posting my answer with few addition.

**Disable input**

```
$('[id='+inputID+']').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

id of tbody

**Disable click but clickable hand will be there but no request will be submitted to server**

```
 $('[id='+inputID+']').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

id of anchor tag

Thanks,
Pise